# How to cancel the selection when "Drop Down"?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

When enter a value into Combobox and click DropDown button, the whole text will be selected.

How could I remove this effect or cancel selection after clicking DropDown button?

The way I know is resetting "CaretIndex ".

```
var cmbTextBox = (TextBox)com.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", com);
cmbTextBox.CaretIndex = com.Text.Length;
```

I want to know if there is any solution that using "Binding" (MVVM) to achieve it, instead of accessing the Combobox instance.

Answer (score 1):

1. I guess that you don't want to create a custom control for that. And that's the meaning of not "accessing combobox instance".
2. I'd like to strongly discourage you from using binding for sending the combobox instance to a view model. View model's and view's lifetimes are different and that may cause bugs with hard to comprehend stacks. And by definition you won't have MVVM that way, as you'd break the separation.
3. The solution is (Blend) behaviors, see e.g.: https://putridparrot.com/blog/blend-behaviors-in-wpf/. In .NET core world they're replaced with https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf, so a new dependency is needed for your project.
   What's great with behaviors is that they are composable, you can have many simple behaviors for a given control and use some of them if needed. That way you won't have a control explosion, where you produce many similar controls that serve slightly different requirements.